# TSQL Update with three joins

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following TSQL Select statement

```
select s.StudentID, s.LastName, s.FirstName ,o.CourseID, c.CourseTitle, o.Semester, s.Feedback_Status
    from Students as s join StudentEnrollments as se
    on s.StudentID = se.StudentID
    join OfferedCourses as o
    on o.SectionID = se.SectionID
    join Courses as c
    on c.CourseID = o.CourseID
    where  s.StudentID = 4 and o.Semester='spring'
```

this returns the following

```
StudentID   LastName     FirstName  CourseID    CourseTitle  Semester  Feedback_Status
----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
4           Fakhouri     Fadi       1           MathI        Spring          0             
4           Fakhouri     Fadi       5           MathII       Spring          0
```

I wrote an update query to change the feedback_status field for a specific row to 1

```
update s
set s.Feedback_Status = 1
from Students as s join StudentEnrollments as se
on s.StudentID = se.StudentID
join OfferedCourses as o
on o.SectionID = se.SectionID
join Courses as c
on c.CourseID = o.CourseID
where  s.StudentID = 4 and o.Semester='spring' and c.CourseID=1
```

the result I get is

```
StudentID   LastName     FirstName  CourseID    CourseTitle  Semester  Feedback_Status
----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
4           Fakhouri     Fadi       1           MathI        Spring          1           
4           Fakhouri     Fadi       5           MathII       Spring          1
```

the feedback_status field gets updated on both rows, no idea why.  Thanks inadvance for any help

I cannot move the feeback_status, the field is a boolean that tells me if the user entered a feedback.  The application works by entering the studentID and then a linq query (via a datagrid) shows all the courses a student is enrolled in.  Each row in the datagrid has a button next to it to add feedback. I need to record this by using the fedback_status as a flag.

I lookedover the tables and I se the problem, I need to move the feedback_status field to the 
StudentEnrollments table, that way I an have duplicate studentID's and fedback_status's

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're updating `Feedback_Status` in the `Students` table, I presume you only have one record in there for `StudentID` 4. When you do the update the status of that record is set to 1 and then I  think that record appears twice in your results.

You could move the `Feedback_Status` column to another table, maybe `Courses`?